# Table scraping with HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, web-scraping

I would like to scrape the table `t-02` from https://wyniki.tge.pl/wyniki/rdn/ with HTML DOM Parser.
I created simple code but I was getting errors:

> **Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on null in /Users/piotrek/Sites/foo/index.html on line 3**

My first code:

```
<?php
    include ("simple_html_dom.php");
    $html=file_get_html("https://wyniki.tge.pl/pl/wyniki/rdn/");
    $tables=$html->find("table[@class=t-02]");
    foreach($tables->find("tr") as $a) {
        foreach($a->find("td") as $element) {
            echo $element;
        }
    }
?>
```

I changed the code to print innertext and it worked:

```
<?php
    include_once ("simple_html_dom.php");
    $html=file_get_html("https://wyniki.tge.pl/pl/wyniki/rdn/");
    $title=$html->find("table[@class=t-02]",0)->innertext;
    echo $title
?>
```

I changed only code so what was wrong with first approach? What was the reason of fatal error?

Comment: The error is saying that `$html` is null, so I think your file_get_html is not returning anything and may be getting an error. Are you getting any warnings or errors in your php log?

Comment: @AndyC I am new to working with apache, I am trying to look into php log but I have some problems with accessing it but give me a moment I will check it :)

Comment: @AndyC I found in my foo-error_log script folder (Is it that what you meant?) `/Users/piotrek/Sites/foo/info.php'not found or unable to stat`.

Comment: Why not edit your code and indent properly?

Comment: @clearlight I would like to, but I don't know how to approach to it yet.

Comment: @piotr, okay, I did it. Is there not an edit button below your question where you could just edit and save it? Not sure since you are still building your reputation (points) here, so might not be enabled for you yet. See the [2 Minute Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @clearlight thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that the $html object is null, so there is nothing to perform the find method against. Do you have the simple_html_dom.php file in the same directory?

Comment: Yes, I have checked it before with simple text scrapping from the webpage and it worked. I used same file, only changed code and restarted server.